# Using 7zip to archive file by older than 5 daya

Tags: 7zip

i wanted to archive folder olden than 5 days.it seems set ARCHIVE_FILE_OLDER_THEN=-to5d is not working. can someone what i can add to archive files to 5 days .Previously it was working for RAR but not working 7z

```
set EDI832_US_ARCHIVE_DIR=C:\apps\harmony\data\EDI832\US\archive


REM -------------------- FILE NAME LIST ---------------------------------


set EDI832_US_FILE=EDI832_US_ARCHIVE


REM --------------- Extra CommandLine Parameters --------------------------------

REM Exclude file types for archiving
REM set EXCLUDE_FILES_TYPES=-x!*.rar -x!*.zip -x!*.7z
set EXCLUDE_FILES_TYPES=-xr!*.zip 

REM Delete files after archiving
set DELETE_AFTER_ARCHIVE=-sdel

REM Archive files only older then days
set ARCHIVE_FILE_OLDER_THEN=-to5d


set EXTRA_PARAM=%EXCLUDE_FILES_TYPES% %DELETE_AFTER_ARCHIVE% %ARCHIVE_FILE_OLDER_THEN%


REM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


REM Path to WinRAR executable in Program Files
set path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip";%path%
REM $Env:Path = $Env:Path + ";C:\Program Files\7-Zip"

REM Set your WinRAR installation path for local testing
REM set path="C:\Program Files\7-Zip";%path%


REM Replace space in hour with zero if it's less than 10
SET hr=%time:~0,2%
IF %hr% lss 10 SET hr=0%hr:~1,1%

REM This sets the date like this: mm-dd-yr-hrminsecs1/100secs
Set TODAY=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%-%hr%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%%time:~9,2%


IF EXIST %EDI832_US_ARCHIVE_DIR% (
    cd %EDI832_US_ARCHIVE_DIR%
    **7z a "%EDI832_US_FILE%_%TODAY%" %EXTRA_PARAM%**
```